# f2py: Exposing parameters from "used" modules

Tags: python, numpy, fortran90, f2py

I assume that this question has been addressed somewhere, but I have spent an inordinate amount of time looking around for the answer including digging into the source code a bit.  I have tried to put the problem in the first paragraph.  The rest shows a basic example of the problem.

I am attempting to compile a module that contains a `USE` statement pointing to another, more general, module.  I would prefer to keep the used module separate so that it can be used in several "packages" as a set of general settings.  When I compile the two modules using f2py everything works as advertised from the fortran side, but from the python side `USE` appears to be ignored.  If I allow f2py to generate a signature file, the file contains a `USE` statement as is appropriate, but if I complete the compilation and import from the resulting library the parameters from the used module are not available in the module that contains the use statement.  Below are two modules illustrating the situation:

```
MODULE test
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: a = 1
END MODULE test

MODULE test2
    USE test
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: b = 2
END MODULE test2
```

In order to show the intermediate step I ran `f2py -h test.pyf test.f90 test2.f90`.  The following signature file is generated; note that the "test2" module contains "use test":

```
!    -*- f90 -*-
! Note: the context of this file is case sensitive.

python module test ! in
    interface  ! in :test
        module test ! in :test:test.f90
            integer, parameter,optional :: a=1
        end module test
        module test2 ! in :test:test2.f90
            use test
            integer, parameter,optional :: b=2
        end module test2
    end interface
end python module test

! This file was auto-generated with f2py (version:2).
! See http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/
```

If I now compile with `f2py --fcompiler=gfortran -c test.pyf test.f90 test2.f90` I obtain test.so (same as running `f2py --fcompiler=gfortran -m test -c test.f90 test2.f90` without creating the signature file first).  Importing from this library in python exposes test.test.a and test.test2.b, but does not expose test.test2.a as can be seen here:

```
In [1]: import test

In [2]: print test.test.a
1

In [3]: print test.test2.b
2

In [4]: print test.test2.a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/users/solbrig/svn_checkouts/inversion/satmet/branches/solbrig/rootpath/data/users
/GeoIPS/src/test/<ipython-input-4-bffcf464e408> in <module>() 
----> 1 print test.test2.a

AttributeError: a
```

Just to illustrate that `b` is defined properly in test2 from the perspective of fortran, the following code uses test2 and prints both `b` and `b`:

```
SUBROUTINE run_test()
    USE test2
    IMPLICIT NONE
    print *, "a = ", a
    print *, "b = ", b
END SUBROUTINE run_test
```

After compiling with "f2py -m run_test -c test.f90 test2.f90 run_test.f90" and obtaining run_test.so, run_test can be imported in python and works as expected:

```
In [1]: import run_test

In [2]: run_test.run_test()
 a =            1
 b =            2
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

#### **TL;DR** : When an F90 module that contains a `USE` is compiled by f2py it does not expose the parameters that are defined in the "used" module as attributes in Python.

Comment: Try to contact f2py developers. It may be a bug.

Comment: I'll give it a shot but they don't seem to be doing much in the last couple of years. I sent this question to the scipy mailing list.

Comment: @Vorticity I wanted to read your question there but I haven't found the thread. Can you link it?

Comment: @Juanlu001 Hey, sorry for taking so long to do this, but I just posted this issue to the numpy git repo.  I'll see if I can dig out the scipy email, but I got no response on the question.  The git issue is located at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3562

Comment: @Vorticity Why don't you post an answer about it? This will come off the unanswered list.

Comment: This is a bug, which has been reported here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3562

Comment: I think there is a temporary solution to this problem that I will post about on Monday after I have had a chance to test it out.  I am also currently looking into the f2py source to work on a more optimal solution.

Comment: @Marcin I added the temporary solution as an answer.  Its pretty simple, but not really what I had hoped.  Hopefully I'll get a chance to spend some time with the f2py source soon.

Comment: @Juanlu001 I added the temporary solution as an answer. Its pretty simple, but not really what I had hoped. Hopefully I'll get a chance to spend some time with the f2py source soon.

Comment: @Vorticity the f2py source is the most entangled nightmare I have ever seen, so good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a temporary solution to this problem, but it is not optimal.  I will continue to work through the f2py source so that I can better understand it and fix the problem within the code itself.  Until then, this is my solution which was inspired by [chatcannon's comment to the issue I posted to nympy's github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3562#issuecomment-24469055).

There are several ways to approach this problem from a temporary standpoint including a couple of ways of modifying the .pyf files.  I don't want to have to modify the .pyf files as it becomes very cumbersome as part of a larger package.  To avoid this, I added f2py directives to my f90 source.

Taking the example from my original question:

```
MODULE test
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: a = 1
END MODULE test

MODULE test2
    USE test
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: b = 2
END MODULE test2
```

simply add an f2py directive in test2 to show f2py how to define `test2.a`:

```
MODULE test
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: a = 1
END MODULE test

MODULE test2
    USE test
    !f2py integer, parameter :: a  ! THIS EXPOSES `a` in `test2`
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: b = 2
END MODULE test2
```

Importing from the resulting `test.so` correctly exposes `test2.a`:

```
In [1]: import test

In [2]: print test.test.a
1

In [3]: print test.test.b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
.../test_solution/<ipython-input-3-798b14f59815> in <module>()
----> 1 print test.test.b

AttributeError: b

In [4]: print test.test2.a
1

In [5]: print test.test2.b
2
```