# f2py use module - signature file

Tags: python, module, fortran, f2py

i created my signature file which is using the module dimpar.
When i try to compile using the signature file, f2py doesn't recognize the msects and maxpar and as a result i get:

```
/tmp/tmpj4zcO9/src.linux-i686-2.6/AtlasGeneratormodule.c:360: error: ‘msects’         undeclared here (not in a function)
/tmp/tmpj4zcO9/src.linux-i686-2.6/AtlasGeneratormodule.c:413: error: ‘maxpar’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/tmp/tmpj4zcO9/src.linux-i686-2.6/AtlasGeneratormodule.c:413: error: initializer element is not constant
/tmp/tmpj4zcO9/src.linux-i686-2.6/AtlasGeneratormodule.c:413: error: (near initialization for ‘f2py_parms_def[0].dims.d[0]’)
/tmp/tmpj4zcO9/src.linux-i686-2.6/AtlasGeneratormodule.c:360: error: ‘msects’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/tmp/tmpj4zcO9/src.linux-i686-2.6/AtlasGeneratormodule.c:413: error: ‘maxpar’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/tmp/tmpj4zcO9/src.linux-i686-2.6/AtlasGeneratormodule.c:413: error: initializer element is not constant
```

How do i make f2py understand that those parameters are coming from the module?

Thanks

**Signature file**:

```
!    -*- f90 -*-
! Note: the context of this file is case sensitive.

python module AtlasGenerator ! in 
interface  ! in :AtlasGenerator
    subroutine loadhistogramdata(wdo,xlat,xlon,ah,nhs,nhb,fs,bins) ! in :AtlasGenerator:AtlasGenerator.f90
        use dimpar  
          ... 
        real dimension((msects)) :: a
        real dimension((msects)) :: c
          ...    
        real dimension((maxpar)) :: param
          ...
    end subroutine loadhistogramdata
end interface 
end python module AtlasGenerator

! This file was auto-generated with f2py (version:2).
! See http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/
```

**the module dimpar**:

```
 module dimpar

  parameter (msects=36) 

  parameter (maxpar=80) 

 end module dimpar
```

***Here is some sample code to replicate the problem:***

**dimpar.f90**

```
module dimpar

      parameter (msects=36) 
end module dimpar
```

**Array.f90**

```
SUBROUTINE FIB(A,N)

use dimpar
REAL*8 A(msects)
DO I=1,N
 IF (I.EQ.1) THEN
    A(I) = 0.0D0
 ELSEIF (I.EQ.2) THEN
    A(I) = 1.0D0
 ELSE 
    A(I) = msects
 ENDIF
ENDDO
END
```

Once compiled i run:

```
f2py -m useArray -h useArray.pyf array.f90

f2py --fcompiler=gfortran -c useArray.pyf array.o dimpar.o
```

Comment: Is that valid Fortran code? Shouldn't it be `integer,parameter :: msects=36, maxpar=80`?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: Those lines appear to compile with ifort and gfortran.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Yeah, I looked it up in the book of [Chapman](http://www.amazon.com/Fortran-2003-Scientists-amp-Engineers/dp/0073191574/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1382105045&sr=8-1&keywords=chapman+fortran). I'm not too firm with FORTRAN 77.

Comment: Did you compile `dimpar`?

Comment: Yes dimpar is compiled and seems to work in the cases where his paramters are not used directly in the signature file like in this case. I may be wrong but i was thinking that my case looks somehow similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156125/f2py-exposing-parameters-from-used-modules Could it be that i need to use something like `!f2py integer, parameter :: a` like in the solution there proposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, to make it work i need to put in the signature file the the module too:

```
f2py -m useArray -h useArray.pyf dimpar.f90 array.f90
```